# delegate not being called when not directly navigated

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, delegates, protocols

I have created three view controllers, namely `FirstViewController`, `SecondViewController` & `ThirdViewController`. The `FirstViewController` pushes `SecondViewController`, and similarly `SecondViewController` pushes `ThirdViewController`.

The `ThirdViewController` is a UITableViewController.

The `SecondViewController` and `ThirdViewController` have custom protocols. Both of them are pass some value to `FirstViewController` using their respective delegates.

The problem is that `SecondViewController` is successfully passing on the value to `FirstViewController`, but the `ThirdViewController` is not being able to do it.

Is it because the `SecondViewController` is directly being navigated from `FirstViewController`, so it is able to pass it, and `ThirdViewController` is not connected with the `FirstViewController` so it is not being able to pass the data?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

The `FirstViewController` just pushes `SecondViewController` through a button action.

The `SecondViewController.h` is:

```
@protocol secondViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)didCompleteSending:(NSArray *)array;

@end


@interface secondView : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *footballPlayers;
@property (assign) id<secondViewDelegate>delegate;
- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnGoToThirdView:(id)sender;
```

The `SecondViewController.m` is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

footballPlayers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Rooney",@"Van Persie",@"Ronaldo",@"Kagawa", nil];
}

- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender {
[delegate didCompleteSending:footballPlayers];
}
- (IBAction)btnGoToThirdView:(id)sender {
thirdView *objthirdView = [[thirdView alloc]init];
objthirdView.delegate=self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objthirdView animated:YES];
}
```

Similarly I have for `ThirdViewController`.

In `FirstViewController.h`
    -(void)didSendDetailsFromThirdView:(NSString *)colors{
    NSLog(@"selected string is = %@",colors);
    }

```
-(void)didCompleteSending:(NSArray *)array{
  for (NSString *str in array) {
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
  }
 }
```

The `-(void)didSendDetailsFromThirdView:(NSString *)colors` does not get called from 'ThirdViewController'.

SECOND EDIT

```
- (IBAction)btnGoToThirdView:(id)sender {
FirstViewController *objFirstViewController = [FirstViewController alloc]init];
thirdView *objthirdView = [[thirdView alloc]init];
objthirdView.delegate=objFirstViewController;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objthirdView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: so FirstViewController is the delegate of ThirdViewController and SecondViewController ?

Comment: yes!! FirstViewController is the delegate of both ThirdViewController and SecondViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the delegate of the `ThirdViewController` in the the `SecondViewController`.m to self

```
objthirdView.delegate=self;
```

this means that the delegate of the `ThirdViewController` is the `SecondViewController` and not the `FirstViewController`. Keep a reference to the `FirstViewController` in the `SecondViewController` and use it as the delegate like this.

```
objthirdView.delegate=myFirstViewController;
```

Assuming it is not possible to pop from `ThirdViewController` to the `FirstViewController` you can maybe misuse the `SecondViewController` for passing the data back to the `FirstViewController` via delegate methods you already implemented. But I would not recommend it - it is not a good design.

Comment: i did that, and now it throws an exception stating bad access!

Comment: it keeps on saying that `secondViewDelegate` is wrongly placed, and then throws bad access exception. Any idea how to go about it/